# Why my compiler doesn't allow overriding a deleted non-throwing virtual member function as a deleted throwing member function?

Tags: c++, overriding, virtual-functions, noexcept, deleted-functions

I've read from C++ primer 5th ed. That a `virtual` member function that won't throw (`noexcept`) must be overriden as non-throwing function. The exception is if the `virtual` member function is defined as a 'deleted' member.

So I've tried this:

```
struct Foo{
    virtual void func() const noexcept = delete;
};

struct Bar : Foo{
    virtual void func() const noexcept(false) override = delete; // or let the compiler make it implicitly a throwing function  
};
```

- But when I compile the code I get the error:

  ```
  looser exception specification on overriding virtual function ‘virtual void Bar::func() const noexcept (false)’|
  ```
- I've searched on cppreference and found the same idea:

> If a virtual function is non-throwing, all declarations, including the definition, of every overrider must be non-throwing as well, unless the overrider is defined as deleted. Here is the code from cppreference:

```
    struct B {
       virtual void f() noexcept;
       virtual void g();
       virtual void h() noexcept = delete;
    };
    struct D: B {
       void f();              // ill-formed: D::f is potentially-throwing, B::f is non-throwing
       void g() noexcept;     // OK
       void h() = delete;     // OK
    };
```

And when I compile the program from cppreference I get the same error as my example. (apart from `f()`  which shouldn't compile). So consider I comment out `void f();` in `struct D`. the compiler complains the same for `void h() = delete;`.

So What is wrong with my compiler? Thank you!

N.B: I've tried the code from cppreference on their website and commented out `f()` in struct `D` and the code didn't compile too?!! So is this an error on he website too?

Example with clang and gcc: https://www.godbolt.org/z/f7hzbG

Comment: `noexcept(false)` declares that the function **is** allowed to throw.  You are doing exactly what the book instructs you not to do.

Comment: @DrewDormann: What about the cppreference example then?

Comment: @DrewDormann  I think the important thing is the `= deleted`  So the rule about not doing it doesn't apply to deleted functions...

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38279368/is-there-any-point-in-declaring-a-deleted-function-as-noexcept

Comment: Visual Studio does accept it in C++17 mode. Maybe the other compilers haven't implemented that detail yet, you could report it to them.

Comment: @MarcGlisse: I've run it on VC++ online IDE: `https://rextester.com/l/cpp_online_compiler_visual` but doesn't compile too! I got this error: `Error(s):
source_file.cpp(10): error C2694: 'void Bar::func(void) noexcept(false) const': overriding virtual function has less restrictive exception specification than base class virtual member function 'void Foo::func(void) noexcept const'
source_file.cpp(10): note: see declaration of 'Bar::func'
source_file.cpp(6): note: see declaration of 'Foo::func'
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.00.23506 for x64`

Comment: Did you enable C++17 mode as I suggested? It does compile on godbolt.

Comment: @MarcGlisse: Yes I've tried it using C++17 on VC++ and it works.